# Can a monster race become playable race in Pathfinder?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, character-creation, monsters, races

I've been wonder and haven't been able to get a clear answer to the question before and I've asked my GM about and received the response, "Look it up yourself."

**I wanted to know if it was within the rules of Pathfinder to convert a monster into a playable character to use?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer to your question can be found [here](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/bestiary/monstersAsPCs.html).

Essentially, yes you can play as a monster race but there are come balance concerns, especially if the party is a mix of monster races and core races.